# Conditional Formatting of donut chart

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint, conditional-formatting, donut-chart

All,

I have a donut chart that indicates widgets that passed inspection as a percentage over total widgets (passed and failed).  What I am trying to do is add some kind of conditional formatting to the ring segment that shows percentage of widgets that passed inspection, based on the percentage of widgets that actually passed inspection, such that the whole segment is either red if less than 75% passed, yellow if up to 90% passed, and green if over 90%

Answer (score 0):

All,

Just thought I'd let you know I found a way to accomplish this.  First, I created a column chart for widgets and for my different color schemes (such that we would have a clustered column chart with two clusters).  Then, I set the widgets passed column chart to a secondary axis.

Next, I changed the chart type of both axis to a donut chart (note, donut charts do not let you set a secondary axis directly, which is why we have to do this in a column chart or line chart first).

Next, for the data series representing the different colors, I used the formulas =if([passed]>=.9,1,0), =if([passed]>=.75,1-R[-1]C,0), and 1-sum(R[-2]C:R[-1]C) to fill the values for the ring on the primary axis that is to represent different colors.

After this, it was simply a matter of adjusting the formatting on the primary and secondary axis, making the [passed] ring segment transparent, and using 1-[passed] to calculate a failed segment of widgets.

I hope that made sense to anyone else trying to accomplish this, but let me know if any questions (or if you have done this before and have a better way to explain, fill free to edit this).